# Trying to call Javascript function from innerhtml

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am trying to display a map upon clicking a button.My code is as follows.

```
  List.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="'+calcRoute()+'">';

    function calcRoute() {
                var start = "san bernardino, ca";
                var end = "los angeles, ca";
                var request = {
                    origin:start,
                    destination:end,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                };
                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        return directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    }
                });
    }
```

calcRoute shows up as undefined while debugging. I want to display the directions between two points of interest upon clicking the button.

Comment: Maybe I am totally wrong, but I think you shouldn't use "'+function+'", but just function. Your code: ` ... onclick="calcRoute()" >`

Comment: I have already tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of this?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `calcRoute` function when building the HTML:

```
List.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="'+calcRoute()+'">';
// ----------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but `calcRoute` doesn't return anything so you're effectively saying:

```
List.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="' + undefined + '">';
```

Perhaps you just want:

```
List.innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="calcRoute()">';
```

so that `calcRoute` will be called when you click on the button.

Comment: I tried doing that as well but it throws up an error saying calcRoute is not defined. I don't understand why it is not able to find the function.

Comment: You need to supply more context. [This version](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Yk5sq/), for example, works just fine because `calcRoute` is globally accessible. [This version](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/k8B2E/) fails because `calcRoute` is defined inside a function so it cannot be seen outside that function. The only difference between those examples is that the first is set up as "No wrap = in <body>" and the second is "onLoad" in the sidebar. That's why I was asking for more context.

Comment: yes, you are right about the function being globally accessible. currently it is nested within another function, but I tried putting calcRoute() function after the closing brackets of function intialize()  and I still get undefined.

Comment: ok.i managed to get a sample code working.am new to JS.I put it below the list.innerHTML outside the other functions and the function is being called.but I don't know how to display the map in a new page upon clicking the button.I tried window.open(directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)); and a new page comes up but it is blank.

Comment: First, you really should stop using `onclick` attributes period, attaching handler functions directly avoids a lot of these scoping problems. Second, that last comment looks like another question to me.